# Does Github Markdown support title attribute?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I want to add a title attribute to a link, which will show up when the user holds the mouse pointer it. Title attributes are helpful if your link text is not descriptive enough to tell users where they're going. (In reference links, you can use optionally parentheses for the link title instead of quotation marks.)

Github Markdown's seems do not support title attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ithub Markdown's seems do not support title attribute.

Yet, [GFM specs mentions](https://github.github.com/gfm/#links):

> A link contains link text (the visible text), a link destination (the URI that is the link destination), and optionally a **[link title](https://github.github.com/gfm/#link-title)**.

```
[link](/uri "title")
```

Give:

```
<p><a href="/uri" title="title">link</a></p>
```